# Definir o valor 0 quando o número for negativo

Tags: mysql

Como posso atribuir 0 quando o valor na coluna no MySQL for negativo? Ou existe algum tipo de dados que só tenha números positivos?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Defina sua coluna como `unsigned` (sem sinal) isso garante que apenas valores positivos zero e null sejam entradas válidas.

Nesse exemplo o primeiro insert já retorna o erro:

> Data truncation: Out of range value for column 'n' at row 1

Ou se conveter os erros para warnings o -1 irá torna-se 0.

```
create table t(
  id int(11) auto_increment primary key,
  n int(11) unsigned
);

insert into t (n) values(-1);
insert into t (n) values(2);
insert into t (n) values(0);
insert into t (n) values(null);
```

**[Exemplo - sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0d6b88)**

Answer (score 5):

Complementando as demais respostas, caso não possa alterar a estrutura de sua tabela para utilizar o `unsigned` como mencionado nas outras respostas, uma alternativa é utilizar a função [`GREATEST`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest).

[Exemplo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6279a1/1) (sqlfiddle):

```
SELECT GREATEST(id, 0) from teste;
```

A função irá mostrar o maior valor entre `id` e `0`, ou seja, se o valor de `id` for negativo, irá apresentar o zero.

Answer (score 1):

Para não utilizar sinais, utilize unsigned, pergunta já respondida no stackoverflow em inglês.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13225461/add-a-positive-integer-constraint-to-a-integer-column-in-mysql

Para limitar o valor da coluna você poderia usar Check Constraint porem o MySQL não tem suporte para esse tipo de constraint, dai você pode criar uma thrigger para executar o comportamento desejado.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7522026/how-do-i-add-a-check-constraint-to-a-table